# Joi Validation - Field is not required when the condition is not met

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I am writing an update endpoint in nodeJs. I want to make sure that additional fields wont be allowed, if certain flags are checked.

```
all_restaurant: Joi.boolean().required(),
merchant_id: Joi.when('all_restaurant',{'is':false, 
                then: Joi.string().required(), otherwise:Joi.disallow()})
```

If all_restaurant is true, I need to throw an error when the user tries to include any merchant_id, but it still allowing me to update.
I tried using strict() after the field and in the top level but nothing is working. is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Joi.forbidden](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyforbidden) instead of Joi.disallow:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    all_restaurant: Joi.boolean().required(),
    merchant_id: Joi.string().when('all_restaurant', {
        is: false, 
        then: Joi.required(), 
        otherwise: Joi.forbidden()
    })
})
```

As the name suggests, forbidden marks a key as forbidden.

Comment: What if the all_restaurant=['A'] and I need to validate based on the all_restaurant[0] === 'A' then merchant_id would be required, what would be the syntax for this array. Could you please help me on this? Thanks. @soltex

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I have added a new answer that should solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant asked by [@shubham-verma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7193018/shubham-verma) (asked on the answer above).

Imagine that `all_resturant` is an array with valid strings: `'A'`, `'B'` or `'C'`:

```
all_resturant: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

How can we make merchant_id required only if all_resturant[0] is equal to 'A'?

We can still use [.when](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anywhencondition-options)  combined with [.ordered](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayorderedtype):

```
Joi.object({
  all_resturant: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('A', 'B', 'C')),
  merchant_id: Joi.string()
}).when(Joi.object({ all_resturant: Joi.array().ordered(Joi.string().valid('A')).items(Joi.string()) }).unknown(), {
  then: Joi.object({
    merchant_id: Joi.required()
  })
})
```

`Joi.array().ordered(Joi.string().valid('A')).items(Joi.string()`) means that the array must have first item as `"A"` and 1 or more subsequent items as one strings.

Here are a few cases:

`{ all_resturant: ["A", "B", "A", "C"] }`
// merchant_id required

`{ all_resturant: ["C", "B", "A", "C"] }`
// passed

`{ all_resturant: ["C"] }`
// passed

`{ all_resturant: ["A"] }`
// merchant_id required

`{ all_resturant: ["A"], merchant_id: '123' }`
// passed

Comment: Thanks @soltex, Its working for me.

But what if I don't want the order of the `all_resturant`. Means if all_resturant containes `A` (any position in the array) then `merchant_id` should be required. Could you please provide syntax for that, I explored the Joi doc but unable to find it. Thanks again

Comment: I used this, but its not working:

```.when(
    Joi.object({
        all_resturant: Joi.array()
            .single(Joi.string().valid('A'))
            .items(Joi.string())
    }).unknown(),
    {
        then: Joi.object({
            merchant_id: Joi.required()
        })
    }
)```

Comment: @ShubhamVerma replace `.ordered` with `.items` and add a `.required`, like this:
`all_resturant: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('A').required()).items(Joi.string())`

Comment: I can update the answer if needed